# uneditable date-time source for vb.net ms access

Tags: microsoft-access, date-time, timestamp, vb.net

We are trying to create a time-in/time-out system using vb.net and ms access as database. I'd like to ask for an uneditable source for our date-timestamp. We can easily use system time but users tend to change the system time.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), or flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: [How to Allow or Prevent Specific Users and Groups from Changing the Date and Time in Windows](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/113557-date-time-allow-prevent-users-groups-changing.html)

Answer (score 0):

In vb.net you can use datetime and make the property uneditable for that field. When the user clicks save or whatever you can the push the datetime to access

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP already said "We can easily use system time but users tend to change the system time."

Answer (score 0):

use system time but use strong encryption algorithm when saving the date and time so that if they will try to change the data in MSAccess its unreadable.